# HTML. Как отменить абсолютное позиционирование по родительскому элементу?

Tags: html, css

Есть следующая html структура:

```
<body>
   <div style="position: relative;">
      <div id="my_elem" style="position: absolute;">
         any content
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Как сделать так чтобы элемент по id `my_elem` позиционировался по body, т.е. нужно как-то проигнорировать `position: relative` у родительского элемента, возможно для этого есть какое-то специальное свойство, найти ответ в гугле если честно не получилось?

P.S. Убрать у родительского элемента `position: relative` нельзя, т.к. на этом завязаны другие элементы, также как и нельзя перенести элемент `my_elem`

Comment: position: fixed - не подойдет?

Comment: position: fixed также идёт по родительскому элементу.

Comment: написать `position: relative !important` ну или, то что вам актуально

Comment: А зачем здесь `position: relative !important`, он будет просто перебивать все назначенные стили, но тут дело не в этом. Или я как-то не так понял вас, какому элементу нужно добавить данное свойство?

Comment: Можете описать задачу полностью? Так как часто в самой задаче кроется ответ, а тут лишь доля задачи, как понимаю. Скорее всего решение вашей задачи иным методом нужно реализовать.

Comment: не меняя разметку - никак

Comment: position: fixed - не идет по родительскому, выпадает из потока https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/usw0yfak/

Comment: Ограничение на перенос элемента `my_elem` имеет какое-то религиозное значение? Если нет, но доступа к коду этого места тоже нет, скриптом скопируйте этот элемент и вставьте его первым чайлдом в `body`, а в изначальном месте удалите.